# Probability of sum of bernoulli's trials.

Tags: probability

Let $X_1,X_2,...,X_n$ be and $Y_1,...,Y_n$ be two sequences of independent Bernoulli trials with $P(X_i=1)=p_i,P(Y_i=1)=q_i$ and $p_i\leq q_i$ for $i=1,...,n$. Let $S_n = \sum_1^n X_i, T_n=\sum_1^n Y_i$. Then prove that $P(S_n\geq j) \leq P(T_n \geq j)$ for all $1\leq j \leq n$ by mathematical induction.

First I showed that for $j=1$.

Second I assume that $P(S_n \geq j) \leq P(T_n \geq j) $ for some $j$.

$$P(S_n \geq j+1) \begin{align}
= P(S_n \geq j) - P(S_n=j)
\leq P(T_n \geq j) - P(S_n=j) \end{align}$$

Could you give me a some tip?

Comment: Have you tried proving this by doing induction on $n$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A proof without induction so not really an answer to your question, but it might interest you anyway.

Let $r_i\in[0,1]$ such that $r_iq_i=p_i$, and let $U_1,\dots,U_n$ be a sequence of independent Bernouilli trials with $P(U_i=1)=r_i$.

Also let it be that there is independence between $Y_i$ and $U_i$ for every $i$.

If $Z_i:=Y_iU_i$ then $Z_1,\dots,Z_n$ is also a sequence of independent Bernouilli trials. This in such a way that $X_i$ and $Z_i$ have equal distribution.

If $R_n:=\sum_{i=1}^nZ_i$ then $R_n$ and $S_n$ have equal distribution

From $R_n\leq T_n$ it follows directly that $\Pr(R_n\geq x)\leq\Pr(T_n\geq x)$ for every $x$.

Combining this with $\Pr(R_n\geq x)=\Pr(S_n\geq x)$ we conclude that $\Pr(S_n\geq x)\leq\Pr(T_n\geq x)$ for every $x$.